# .NET: Shortest possible string representation of a double value

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, double, number-formatting

The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the more compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation. The problem is there still can be leading zeros in exponent.

Example:

```
Double d = 0.000001;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G"));

1E-06
```

Is there a numeric format string that will remove leading zero in exponent so the result is

```
1E-6
```

I still want the function to return fixed-point notation if it is more compact. In other words, I want the shortest string representation of a double value.

edit: I would like to do it without post-processing

Comment: The real question is why you want this.

Comment: `string result = result.Replace("E-0", "E-");` would be hacky - but it would work. ;)

Comment: @mybirthname I am exporting a large amount of data which consists mostly of real numbers. By removing this one leading zero, the size of exported file is reduced by almost 10%.

Answer (score 1):

You can use post-processing to remove leading zeros.

```
static string Compact(double d)
{
    var s = d.ToString("G");
    if(s.Contains("E-0") || s.Contains("E+0"))
    {
        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+)(E[+-])0+(\d+)", "$1$2$3");
    }

    return s;
}
```

Usage

```
Console.WriteLine(Compact(0.000001)); // result: 1E-6
Console.WriteLine(Compact(12342353465345432313123123123.0)); // result: 1.23423534653454E+28
Console.WriteLine(Compact(0.000011)); // result: 1.1E-5
```

Comment: It would be faster to just check the third and fourth letter from behind of string s, because the exponent is always written at the end (formats E### or E##). Nice shot anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the longhand version of the formatting, and manually selecting the number of digits

```
Double d = 0.000001;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.###E-0"));

1E-6
```

The exact version I have made will round a number like 0.0000012351573 to `1.235E-6`

If you really wanted the shortest you could techincally use

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0E-0"));
```

This will round it but always have only one digit- for example

```
Double d = 0.0000018;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.###E-0"));

2E-6
```